# Insert data from linked server stored procedure into table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, linked-server

We have a setup with a SQL Server 2008 "server1" linked to another SQL server "server2".
On "server2", there is a stored procedure that I can query just fine from "server1":

```
EXEC [server2].[xx].[dbo].[sp] param
```

However, as soon as I start inserting data from the linked server SP, we run into problems.
We use the following code:

```
INSERT INTO server1.dbo.table (column1, column2, ...)
EXEC [server2].[xx].[dbo].[sp] param
```

When we started out, we received the "known" errors like:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "linkedserver" returned message "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.". Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 2 The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "linkedserver" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

As stated in similar questions like:
[inserting to a local table from a linked stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017428/inserting-to-a-local-table-from-a-linked-stored-procedure)
[Inserting Results Of Stored Procedure From Linked Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874697/inserting-results-of-stored-procedure-from-linked-server)

So, we configured MSDTC on both servers. Now the query runs for 20 seconds and then aborts with the error message:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "server2" returned message "No transaction is active.".
>   Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 14
>   The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "server2" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

As opposed to the previous errors, there is nothing in the Windows Event log.

First of all, is my query considered as a distributed transaction because of the INSERT into a local table?

Second, if I try to execute a distributed query like this:

```
begin distributed tran
select * from [server2].master.sys.sysprocesses
commit tran
```

I get the exact same error message after exactly 20 seconds.

I don't know how to investigate further from here. Could it be a firewall issue?

Comment: Try this - http://armaitus.wordpress.com/2011/09/30/sql-server-2008-inserting-from-a-stored-procedure-via-linked-servers/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need distributed transactions, the solution at @rs's link above worked for me. Repeating the solution here:

```
EXECUTE sp_serveroption @server = '<remote_linked_server_name>', @optname = 'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue = 'false';
```

This tells the sql server instance to not promote transactions to the linked server. Be aware this may have other consequences so use with discretion.